# How to filter emails using subject using Outlook Metabot?

Tags: outlook, rpa, automationanywhere

I am using [Perform various outlook operations](https://botstore.automationanywhere.com/bot/perform-various-email-operations/) to automate this process.

I have to filter the emails based on subject which starts with "Automation Anywhere ".

I have used `GetMailIDsArrayByFilter` function. In that i have given input as

> "[subject] = Automation Anywhere certification Master"

without quotes, it works fine if i mention the full subject of the email.

If i have to search for partial subject like "Automation Anywhere", i'm getting error.

i have tried "Automation Anywhere%", "Automation Anywhere-", "Automation Anywhere%"

Can you please help me with this?

i have also raised this in the Automation Anywhere Apeople portal. 
Reference: https://apeople.automationanywhere.com/s/question/0D56F00007x9HToSAM/how-to-filter-emails-using-subject-using-outlook-metabot-

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using -> "Automation Anywhere*"

Comment: Have you tried storing email Subject into a variable and then putting a simple if condition if $subject$ contains Automation Anywhere

Comment: no @Jonx, i have to restrict from the metabot filter itself. i can filter emails based on ReceivedTime and Unread. i need to filter based on Subjects too.